# How to add a custom field to a taxonomy term

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I am developing a module and I would like to know how to add a field to a taxonomy term?

My section is named `special` and I want to add terms in this section

I have this code:

```
function add($form,&$form_state) {
    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('send'),
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'special_add_submit';

    return $form;
}

function special_add_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'nombre',
        'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
        // This is the vocabulary
        'bundle' => 'special',
        'label' => t('Relates to option'),
        'description' => t('This is the description'),
        'required' => true,
        'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
        'settings'=> array(
            'max_width'=>80)
        ),
        );
    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

How to do that?

[image]

i create a field named `name` when i save that field i want to add the value to taxonomy term named `special`

Comment: What is the specific issue you are running into? Usually you create the field instance when enabling a module. Yours should be created when the user submits a form, or should it only save the value? Please update the question, explain what you want to achieve and what does and does not work.

Comment: @skycomputer2 If I understood  correctly you need to add some fields to a taxonomy field? If so, consider to follow the [default way](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/organizing-content-with-taxonomies/add-a-field-to-a-taxonomy-term-drupal-7-and-later) as it is provided by Drupal and don't try to implement it from scratch

Comment: This question makes no sense. You want to create a term programmatically - not add a field to a term. Or is it vice versus? It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i can do it

```
  $newterm = new stdClass();
  $newterm->name = 'fashion'; // The name of the new term
  $newterm->vid = 2; // The ID of the parent vocabulary
  taxonomy_term_save($newterm);
```